# How to spawn threads from a vector of structs to run an impl fn from each struct in the vector?

Tags: multithreading, vector, struct, rust

I have a struct which contains a `Vec` of instances of another base class of struct. I am trying to iterate over the `Vec` and spawn threads which each run a single `impl fn` from the base struct. Nothing needs mutable access at any time after the iteration of thread spawning begins; just some basic math returning an `f64` (based on values in a `HashMap` using keys stored in a fixed `Vec` in each base struct).

I am running into lifetime issues which I don't fully understand and which the compiler error messages (for once) don't help with.

Here is a stripped down version of what I want to implement (with some annotation of the errors encountered):

```
struct BaseStruct {
    non_copy_field: Vec<&'static str>,  // BaseStruct has vector members (thus can't implement Copy).
}

impl BaseStruct {
    fn target_function(&self, value_dict: &HashMap<&'static str, f64>) -> f64 {
        // Does some calculations, returns the result.
        // Uses self.non_copy_field to get values from value_dict.
        0.0
    }
}

struct StructSet {
    values: HashMap<&'static str, f64>,  // This will be set prior to passing to base_struct.target_function().
    all_structs: Vec<BaseStruct>,        // Vector to be iterated over.
}

impl StructSet {
    fn parallel_calculation(&self) -> f64 {
        let mut result = 0.0;

        let handles: Vec<_> = self.all_structs.iter().map(|base_struct| {
            // Complains about lifetime here   ^^^^^ or    ^ here if I switch to &base_struct
            thread::spawn(move || {
                base_struct.target_function(&self.values)
            })
        }).collect();

        for process in handles.iter() {
            result += process.join().unwrap();
        };
        // Shouldn't all base_structs from self.all_structs.iter() be processed by this point?
        result
    } // Why does it say "...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content" here?
}
```

I have been trying various combinations of `RwLock`/`Arc`/`Mutex` wrapping the contents of the fields of `StructSet` to attempt to gain thread-safe, read-only access to each of the elements iterated/passed, but nothing seems to work. I'm looking to keep the codebase light, but I guess I'd consider rayon or similar as I'll need to follow this same process multiple places in the full module.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: [Here's an example of how you could use crossbeam's "scoped threads" feature, as suggested in the answer to the other question.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c0889a8d3e6c6483317f611a6b365e64) Note that you don't need to manually `join` all the handles when using scoped threads since that is part of how they ensure correctness.

Answer (score 1):

Rust's lifetime system needs to know that if you borrow something (i.e. have a reference to it), that underlying value will exist for the whole time that you borrow it. For regular function calls, this is easy, but threads cause problems here - a thread you start may outlive the function you start it from. So you can't *borrow* values into a thread, you have to *move* values into a thread (which is why you have to write `thread::spawn(move || {` not just `thread::spawn(|| {`.

When you call `.iter()` on a `Vec`, the values the iterator produces are *references* to the values in the Vec - they're being borrowed. So you can't use them as-is from another thread. You need to *move* some *owned* value into the thread.

There are a few ways you can go about this:

If you don't need the `Vec` after your processing, you could switch to use `.into_iter()` rather than `.iter()`. This will iterate over the owned values in the `Vec`, rather than borrowing them, which means you can move them into the threads. But because the `Vec` is giving up ownership of the items, your `Vec` stops being usable after that.

If you *do* need your `Vec` after, and your values are clonable (i.e. they implement the `Clone` trait), you could call `.iter().cloned()` instead of `.iter()` - this will make copies of each of the values, which you can then move into the thread.

If you need the `Vec` afterwards, and either your values aren't clonable, or you don't want to clone them (maybe because it's expensive, or because it matters to you that both threads are using the exact same object), you can have your `Vec` store `Arc<BaseStruct>` instead of just `BaseStruct` - but that's not quite enough - you'll *also* need to explicitly clone the values before moving them into the thread (perhaps by using `.iter().cloned()` like above).

A downside of using `Arc`s is that no threads will be able to modify the values in the future. If you want to use `Arc`s, but you ever want o be able to modify the values in the future, you'll need instead of storing an `Arc<BaseStruct>`, to store an `Arc<Mutex<BaseStruct>>` (or an `Arc<RwLock<BaseStruct>>`. The `Mutex` ensures that only one thread can be modifying (or indeed reading) the value at a time, and the `Arc` allows for the cloning (so you can move a copy into the other thread).

Comment: It's worth noting that you'll run into the same issue where you try to use `self.values` because that relies on being able to borrow `self`, which also won't necessarily outlive the thread. Assuming that's somehow clonable (either because it can be cloned itself, or because it is wrapped in an `Arc`), you can write: `let values = self.values.clone();` inside your `map` closure before your `thread::spawn` closure, and then access `values` in the thread instead of `self.values`.

Comment: I like the `.iter().cloned()` option because it leaves the code a bit cleaner, but it runs into a couple other issues. The signature of the closure is finding `for<'r> fn(&'r std::sync::Arc<BaseStruct>) -> _` but is expecting `fn(std::sync::Arc<BaseStruct>) -> _`. And the other issue at the tail where `.collect()` is called because the cloned iterator does not result in an `&mut std::iter::Map`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. Specifically it was the use of `self.all_structs.iter().map()`. Apparently `iter()` was requiring static lifetimes.

I switched to the following and it's working now:

```
fn parallel_calculation(&self) -> f64 {
    let mut handles: Vec<_> = Vec::new();

    for base_struct in &self.all_structs {
        let for_solve = self.for_solve.clone();
        let base_struct = base_struct.clone();

        handles.push(thread::spawn(move || {
            let for_solve = for_solve.read().unwrap();
            base_struct.target_function(&for_solve)
        }));
    };

    let mut result = 0.0;
    for process in handles { result += process.join().unwrap(); };
    return result
}
```

With `Arc`s and an `RwLock` in the main struct as follows:

```
pub struct StructSet {
    all_structs: Vec<Arc<BaseStruct>>,
    for_solve: Arc<RwLock<HashMap<&'static str, f64>>>,
}
```

Comment: It's the `clone`s that fix the problem, not switching from iterators to indexing. Also did you change `base_struct.target_function` to `coefficient.force`?

Comment: I tried the `clone`s in the `iter().map()` version and it still didn't not work. `iter().map()` didn't even seem to work with an empty closure that just returned 0.0 because of lifetime issues. And good catch on the `base_struct.target_function`. Trying to keep all the hydrodynamics bits out to be less confusing. Edited to fix.

Comment: [For example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=83ed30470fc6c89a6a7caeb5f321de1a). (Note the code in the answer also has a bug in that it uses `handles[i] = ...` instead of `handles.push(...)`; it will panic whenever `all_structs` is non-empty.)

Comment: [If you wanted to use `.iter().map(...)` you can still do that with the clones inside.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bf5e6192d1ab1c21891821e3629f0fb0) Equivalently, you could use `iter().cloned().map(...)` and remove the `base_struct.clone()` line.

Comment: Updated for `handles.push()`. Much better!